# Change "content" of .bs-example in Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, pseudo-class

I am trying to get to grips with the new bootstrap version (3.3.0) and in particular I am keen to implement the following tag:

```
<div class="bs-example"></div>
```

By default, this generated `EXAMPLE` as seen on the boostrap doc pages.

In particular, I need the `content` css to change and I was wondering if this is possible using the `style` tag with the html.

I can see that the `content` css variable seems to be in the `::after` class, but, I am unable to change this yet on the example.